# Every time Texmaker is asking to download package

Tags: packages, miktex, texmaker

This may be a trivial question, but bothering me a lot.

I downloaded Texmaker (LaTeX Editor) and MiKTeX to my system. Every time while writing my report, it is asking to download the packages. My friend also downloaded both MiKTeX and Texmaker and it is working fine for him. I don't know what I did wrong while downloading these software.

Comment: which package is it trying to download?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it is saying "tex/latex/movie15\movie15.sty" is missing and will be installed from random package depository.

Comment: then go to the miktex console and try to install the missing package directly. If something fail you will at least see a sensible error message.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can check if your document, or any other file that you load from your document with `\include` or `\input`, contains a reference to the `movie15` package. If so, you can delete that reference, which will probably stop MikTeX from trying to download it. That package is very old and replaced by another package, so it should not be used at all anymore.